# Date field does not display the value in Chrome browser

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome, date, razor

I am having problem binding date value in Chrome browser.

My razor view defined as follow

```
<input id="date1" type="text" class="required" value="@Model.Date.ToShortDateString()"  maxlength="10" />

<input id="date2" type="date" class="required" value="@Model.Date.ToShortDateString()"  maxlength="10" />
```

I ran it under Chrome, the first input display the date value correct. 
the second input only display mm/dd/yyyy even though a calendar display when I click on the down arrow.

I would like to have the second input field to show the value instead of mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Could you show some of the code, please?

Comment: You can not have errors if you do not have code :D

Comment: I edited your question.  The code you posted was just html and you didn't indent to treat it as code, so it wasn't visible.

Answer (score 19):

When you use the new  `<input type="date" ...` in HTML5, you need to pass the value in ISO format, which is `yyyy-MM-dd`.  So change your markup to:

```
<input id="date2" type="date" class="required" value="@Model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"  maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: Dear expert, by following your solution how can i show date dd-mm-yyyy in other browser.

Comment: @karim_fci - Sounds like you are asking a different question.  Please open a new question instead of asking in comments.  Thanks.