# The specified value does not conform to the required format yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, datetime, data-annotations

I have a .Net MVC 5 application that is using Data Annotations, Entity-Framework Jquery 2.1.3 and Jquery UI 1.11.4.

When I render an edit form with an input of type date using the UK format "dd/MM/YYYY"; the following error message appears when using Google Chrome:

> The specified value '10/10/2001' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.  jquery-2.1.3.js:5317

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Column(TypeName = "date"), DataType(DataType.Date), Display(Name = "My date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public string MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Mark up**

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field My date must be a date." id="MyDate" name="MyDate" type="date" value="10/10/2001" />
```

The value is set correctly in the input control but the date does not appear in the browser. I first thought this was an issue with jQuery as it is appearing the jQuery script file, but when testing in IE and Firefox everything is working fine.

I then assumed it was my regional setting in chrome as by default Chrome thinks everyone English is in America, I changed the regional setting to UK and still the same issue appears.

A simple fix would be to change the format in my model to universal but to UK users this is a little alien.

Is there a way to tell chrome that accept date formats in "dd/MM/YYYY"?

Comment: Are you wanting to render the browsers HTML5 datepicker implementation (or are you using a jquery plugin)?

Comment: I suggest you use `datepicker ui` so the ISO format is sent to the server while `dd/MM/dddd` will be configured at client side.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was going to let the browser handle the date picker, so there is one less need for a third party library.

Comment: If your using the browser datepicker, your need to specifiy the attribute as `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyInEditMode = true)]`. The browser will then display the value in the browsers locale settings, but post back the ISO format so it will be correctly bound. But note that this is only supported in modern browsers.

Comment: Doing this also renders the date in universal format when using DisplayFor() helper method

Comment: @AndyClark, Unfortunate side effect, but the html5 specification is that it must be in ISO format. The alternative is to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate, ""{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @type="date" })` and leave the `[DisplayFormat]` as is.

Comment: Thanks, now it all makes sense. Please can you put your comments into an answer and I will happily accept. I will just have to overwrite the default DateTime display template to use the current culture or force the UK format.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The specifications for the HTML5 date picker state that the date must be in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format). This means that you `DisplayFormatAttribute` must be

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public string MyDate { get; set; }
```

Alternatively you can manually add the format using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @type = "date"  })
```

The later option allows you to keep the `DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")` for usage in `@Html.DisplayFor()`

Comment: Is there any less janky workaround than using JS to reformat the box after loading the page? `[DisplayFormat]` causes jQuery to reset the field and give an invalid value message in the console. Formatting it in `TextBoxFor` solves this error (and allows me to apply my mask plugin), but still displays the date in ISO format. On domReady, I move the values around to use American formatting.

Comment: @Sinjai, Sorry, I don't understand your comment. `[DisplayFormat]` and jQuery are not related in anyway (it will not reset a value), and this question/answer relates to the browsers HTML-5 datepicker implementation (it has nothing to do with a mask plugin). If your having an issue, then ask a new question with the relevant details

Comment: Yeah, probably too much for an aside in a comment. I don't have any better way to word it for a question, though. jQuery is used in ASP.NET MVC projects for validation, and I presume that's what's freaking out. Console just says the error originates in jquery-version.js. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I'm hoping for an answer and it feels stupid writing a formal question about this...
 
`ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` is used to keep the format in `@Html.EditorFor()` right? then howcome I still get that error (the one in the question) in the console when trying to fill an `@Html.EditorFor()` with a `DateTime` and `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`.... Any ideas? or am I confusing `Edit mode` with something else?

Comment: @FllnAngl, If its not working for you, then I can only assume you have other code, or something your not telling us that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need any jquery or ASP feature for fixing it. Simple JS will do just fine.
The problem is that the browser requires the format yyyy-mm-dd.

And toLocaleString doesn't allow the date to be in this format. So after searching I found out that this is ISO format and we can use Date().toISOString() to get the date in the required format.

I used the slice method to extract the date part only because Date().toISOString() returns date with time.

My code:

```
date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing this if your browser is too close to the international date line. I'm at GMT+12:00 and half the time this gives the wrong date.

Answer (score 11):

The issue could be from the type="date".  That was my situation anyway.  Worked once it was changed to type="text".  If the interface is built with an MVC wrapper, you need to replace or set the html attribute accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.
5 years later and this fixed my issue.
Much love.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the InputTagHelper.Format

```
<input asp-for="MyDate" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" />
```

https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Mvc/TagHelpers/InputTagHelper/#prop-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper.Format

Comment: How can I do this only for Chrome.  But not IE?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem
I Did this and it started working

```
<input type="date" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" value=@Model.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") />
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `type` attribute to text.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate, new { @type = "text"  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to highlight something in the answer here.

If you are building an application that has Globalization and Localization then the method of passing in a format using a Html helper will be better. You can also just use EditorFor and pass in the necessary id or class for datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this warning by assigning the value to html5 date input. I just converted to the required format(yyyy-MM-dd) according then its fine.

All my logic is to calculate next date and assign to other date input. I'll share my whole logic.

HTML Code:

```
  <input type='date' name="booking_starts" id="booking_starts" autocomplete="off" />

  <input type='date' name="booking_ends" id="booking_ends" autocomplete="off" />
```

Js Code:

```
   $('#booking_starts').change(function() {
        var start   = $("#booking_starts").val();
        var result  = new Date(start);
        var end     = result.setDate(result.getDate() + 1);
        $("#booking_ends").val(dateToYMD(end));
    });

    function dateToYMD(end_date) {
        var ed = new Date(end_date);
        var d = ed.getDate();
        var m = ed.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = ed.getFullYear();
        return '' + y + '-' + (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this, in my case it was because the day in my date had only one digit and this was messing it up. If your date day is less than 10, make sure to do `new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });`

Answer (score 0):

A simplified solution that worked for me was.

```
  // Format: YYYY-MM-DD
  const day = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
  const month = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "2-digit" });
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();

  // Assign to input variable
  document.getElementById("reservation_date").value = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
```