# Changes not saved when editing EF entry in DB because of DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

First of all, i'm sorry for asking a question which was asked quite a few times, but none of solutions worked for me.

I'm writing so far simple ASP MVC CRUD app, trying to figure out N-tier architecture mostly, and the thing is that in my model class there are DateTime and TimeSpan, when creating and object and saving it to DB everything works more or less, datetime is saved, timespan is saved, deletion works as well, but when i go to Edit an entry in a view, first thing i notice is that datetime for some reasons is not loaded (default "mm/dd/yyyy" is shown instead), however timespan is properly loaded from DB, so i change date manually, hit 'Save' and when i call SaveChanges() on dbContext, it throws exception

> Conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value

[Gist of code snippets](https://gist.github.com/karosas/56fa97a57b7680aedc9d)

This is really weird for me, since creation works, while edit doesn't.

There are quite a few things i tried: changing DB type to datetime2, datetime, changing time field back to time(2), so far i didn't manage to get this working in any way.

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? Eg. what values are you trying to save in `_client.Update`?

Comment: You need to include the code in your question, not an link to it. First change the attribute to `[DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` (ISO format) so the Chrome datepicker will display the correct date

Comment: When adding something (works):
http://i.imgur.com/fWpEwwa.png

When Editing (doesnt work)
http://i.imgur.com/BaiG3cF.png

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, I thought it will make post messy, didn't knew anything about Chrome datePicker, just using default MVC5 template, will try it

Comment: And from the 2 images, its unclear what the issue is. One has a date of `1/1/2016` and the other a date of `3/3/2017`, neither of which will throw that exception. Also refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798906/the-specified-value-does-not-conform-to-the-required-format-yyyy-mm-dd/30801647#30801647) for an explanation of my last comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, according to your images that EF tries to insert one more empty record, when you're trying to update.

When using generate controller window, visual studio generate edit operation as:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Entity entity)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(entity);
}
```

So I can suggest you change your `_client.Update(@event);` for

```
    _client.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _client.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That Fixed thing where in Edit window date wasn't loaded, but still problem persists with conversion between datetime and datetime2