# What is the correct or best practice way to handle date formats with MVC / Razor for different browsers and countries?

Tags: date, razor, browser, format

In my app (MVC 5, bootstrap), I have the default setup from the MVC scaffolding.

I want the dates to appear as dd/mm/yyyy format for UK users. This is the data model/class declaration for the date and the annotations:

```
[Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
[DisplayName("Invoice Date")]
public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
```

This works okay in Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox, Opera or Edge.

On editing this in the latter three, the date just displays dd/mm/yyyy in the edit field, presumably as the browsers provide their own edit controls and rely in some way on a particular form. I'm not sure on that ???

I did some reading and adding this annotation to the date was said to resolve this:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
```

I tried this and it seemed to work, but closer inspection showed the date showing up in the wrong format when being displayed not for editing. And there was some discrepency there across the browsers.

Then when I came back to testing it on IE, the date formats were now wrong.

So my question is, how do you handle this issue properly in MVC/razor across the different browsers? What's the correct or best practice method?

And, of course, what is the best practice method of dealing with this and ensuring the correct date formats for a users culture/country etc?

Thank you in advance.

Using Bootstrap with binding in mvc and EditorFor etc, in the view for example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaymentDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaymentDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaymentDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried Bootstrap.v3.datetimepicker but this did not work in firefox or opera. I obviously want the date picker to have the same look and feel as the other bootstrap components.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Assuming your are using `@Html.EditorFor()` and `@Html.DisplayFor()` (show your code!), then you are generating the browsers HTML-5 datepicker which is not supported in all browsers (not at all in IE, and only in the latest FireFox). If you want consistent UI, then use a jquery datepicker plugin to generate a datepicker

Comment: Refer also the alternative in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798906/the-specified-value-does-not-conform-to-the-required-format-yyyy-mm-dd/30801647#30801647)

Comment: Yes the code is `<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>` --- using bootstrap. Yes, consistent UI is desireable, don't want any square edges on textboxes etc, though.

Comment: Trying to get the bootstrap date picker to work with mvc 5 but it's not playing nicely. :(