# How to Format Date from "yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00" to "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: angular9, core-ui

I am using Angular 9, Core Ui, SQL for my project. `input type="date" (input class="form-control" type="date")` is used for showing date in the html file. While selecting records using SQL Query from a date field in a table, it shows the date as `"2020-01-01T00:00:00"` but no date is showing in the date control.

In `Right click > Inspect > Console`, the following message shows,

The specified value `"2020-01-01T00:00:00"` does not conform to the required format, `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The specified value does not conform to the required format yyyy-MM-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798906/the-specified-value-does-not-conform-to-the-required-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following function and call the function by passing the date as parameter. It will return the date in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.

```
ConvertDateToStringFormat(dt:Date):string{
    dt = new Date(dt);
    var day = ("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    return dt.getFullYear() +"-"+ month +"-" + day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for typescript 4 or later, this will work,

// convert sql date "2019-01-01T00:00:00"/null to date type/undefined

// can't use "==="" for comparsion, as source type is "Date | undefined"

export const ToDate = (source: Date | undefined) => source == undefined ? undefined: new Date(source!);

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format code.