# Need help to display a nullable date value in asp.net razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

How do I display the date below. I am getting the following in the browser console

> The specified value "3/24/2023 12:00:00 AM" does not conform to the
> required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
> [image]

Model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? MovedInDate { get; set; }

address.MovedInDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

View:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="[@i].Address.MovedInDate" value="@Model.Contacts[i].Address.MovedInDate">
```

Answer (score 0):

@marisks has answered to similar post in following link,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801647/3112443

It will help you to resolve the issue you are facing.